# Can ThermodynamicData be used with NSolve?

Tags: equation-solving

Let's say I define a function giving the enthalpy of water:

```
f[t_]:=QuantityMagnitude@ThermodynamicData["Water","Enthalpy",{"Pressure"->Quantity[1,"Bars"], "Temperature"->Quantity[t,"DegreesCelsius"]}]
```

I'd like to use that to find out what temperature corresponds to a given enthalpy:

```
NSolve[f[t]==300000,t]
```

But this gives me no result. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Restrict the argument of `f` to numeric values:

```
Clear[f]
f[t_?NumericQ] := QuantityMagnitude @ ThermodynamicData[
    "Water",
    "Enthalpy",
    {"Pressure"->Quantity[1,"Bars"], "Temperature"->Quantity[t,"DegreesCelsius"]}
]
```

Then, you can just use [`FindRoot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindRoot):

```
FindRoot[f[t] == 300000, {t, 50}]
```

> {t -> 71.6414}

Comment: Interesting. I had tried that with NSolve but it didn't work, so I assumed it wouldn't work with FindRoot either.

Answer (score 6):

How about generating an interpolation over the expected range and use FindRoot like so?

```
f = Interpolation@
   Table[{t, 
     QuantityMagnitude@
      ThermodynamicData["Water", 
       "Enthalpy", {"Pressure" -> Quantity[1, "Bars"], 
        "Temperature" -> Quantity[t, "DegreesCelsius"]}]}, {t, 1, 
     99}];
FindRoot[f[t] - 300000, {t, 50}]
(* {t -> 71.6414} *)
```

Also, if you are just interested in having temperature as a function of enthalpy, you could transpose the table and avoid FindRoot all together.

```
tofh = Interpolation@
   Table[{QuantityMagnitude@
      ThermodynamicData["Water", 
       "Enthalpy", {"Pressure" -> Quantity[1, "Bars"], 
        "Temperature" -> Quantity[t, "DegreesCelsius"]}], t}, {t, 1, 
     99, 10}];
tofh[300000]
(* 71.6414 *)
```

Comment: That's a method I've been considering. I was worried it might be very slow.

Comment: The database call is the slowest part.  Once the table is populated, the interpolations are very fast.

Comment: I'll accept and give it a try. Given that behind the hood it's just calling a database, I doubt it can be made much more efficient than that.

Comment: If you are only interested in the liquid phase region, you need very few points.  If you are near the boiling point, you may need a lot of points to capture the transition.  I got the same answer when I stepped by 10 degrees.